# Networkx not reading in data correctly

Tags: python, csv, graph, networkx

I am trying to read in an edgelist that I have created but the weight values are not being read in correctly by networkx and I am unsure why. I originally did it as a .edgelist file with spaces as seperators and used this line

```
elephG = nx.read_edgelist('elephant.edgelist', nodetype=str, create_using=nx.DiGraph(), data=(('weight',int),))
```

This worked perfectly fine and everything was read in, however I needed to then make a graph that was a combination of multiple graphs (The same thing just with a lot more edges) This is where problems arose. I noticed that the degrees where not totaling up properly. I took a look at the edges using:

```
allG.in_edges('China', data=True)
```

and some of the edge values are indeed being read in wrong. Does anyone know why this would be? I tried manipulating the file from a txt file to a edgelist file to a csv file but all the formats read it wrong.

Here is what I am currently doing

```
#Make a master graph
allG = nx.read_edgelist('master.csv',  delimiter=",", create_using=nx.DiGraph(), data=(('weight',int),))
allG.in_edges('China', data=True)
```

I also noticed that when I delete a large portion of the lines from the end, it begins to read in weights correctly again (I only have 167 lines btw, so its by no means super massive)

I cant post the whole thing as its rather large but here is a snippit of the output as well as the beginning of the file

Output: 
`InEdgeDataView([('South_Africa', 'China', {'weight': 3}), ('Belgium', 'China', {'weight': 1}), ('France', 'China', {'weight': 1}), ('Germany', 'China', {'weight': 1}), ('Hong_Kong', 'China', {'weight': 5}), ('India', 'China', {'weight': 9}),`

File: `South_Africa,Vietnam,20
South_Africa,China,15
South_Africa,Mozambique,12
South_Africa,Thailand,4
South_Africa,Malaysia,1
South_Africa,Hong_Kong,1
Cambodia,Vietnam,1
Belgium,China,1
Belgium,Ireland,1
Belgium,South_Korea,1
Belgium,Taiwan,1
China,Vietnam,1
China,Hong_Kong,1
Czech_Republic,Ireland,1
Ethiopia,Thailand,2
France,China,1
France,Vietnam,1
France,Ireland,1
Germany,South_Korea,1
Germany,Taiwan,1
Germany,China,1
Guinea,Uganda,1
Hong_Kong,Vietnam,2
Hong_Kong,China,2
India,Vietnam,5
India,China,1`

As you can see the first and last two weights of china have been read incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the data parameter is wrong. From the [doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html) `data=` is a bool or a list of tuples. Here you are using a single tuple `(('weight',int),)`.

You may want to try testing `data=True`. I believe that networkx has a default weight attribute.